Dispute cancellation fees by 3rd-party airline booking
I booked a flight through Gotogate. Almost immediately, I realized there was an error on my end. I chatted to them about canceling and they said there would be $250 worth of cancelation fees from them in addition to the actual airline's. I would like to know what my chances are of successfully disputing these charges through my Chase credit card.

Did you cancel within 24 hours? Was the flight more than 7 days later? I suppose you are in the US?

How many passengers/flights are involved? They list fees of $43 per passenger for cancellations/refunds.

@jcaron I haven't canceled yet because of those fees but I did chat w/ Gotogate w/in an hour buying the tickets. The flight is more than 7 days later. We're 5.

What was the error?

@Traveller I picked up a flight that would arrive too late to the destination and we have little ones.


I would like to know what my chances are of successfully disputing these charges through my Chase credit card.

Your chances depend a lot on local laws AND the exact terms and conditions of the ticket, which you agreed to when you made the booking.
For example,if you are covered by the US 24 hour free cancellation (see for example https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/notice-24hour-reservation), then your chances are very good.
If local laws don't provide free cancellation and the terms and conditions state a $250 cancelling fee plus airline cancelling fees, your chances are very small indeed.
Fully refundable tickets are typically a lot more expensive than non-refundable ones. The airline or booking agent will not provide this benefit for free unless they are legally required to.

Thanks @Hilmar. Is local referring to me or to the company? I live in the U.S.

Also, thank you for the link!

The biggest problem is that they make it very difficult to cancel the ticket by demanding that I call the carrier directly which will probably set me back 30-45 mins of hold time and $50. They have this all terribly set up.

"Terribly set up" from your perspective, but ideally set up from theirs. They don't WANT you to be able to cancel tickets for free, they WANT to be able to keep the cancellation charges.

@juanchito: "local" is complicated. It depends primarily on the flight routing (from or to the US). The exact policy is hard to read and many 3rd party agents claim that it applies to direct airline booking. Which is another reason to NOT book with a 3rd party agent like Gotogate.

calling disputes dept for my credit card tomorrow to get some sort of idea what are my options.

@juanchito Good luck! I do recommend having the terms and conditions of your booking handy.
